# How to restore local files deleted due to git prune

Tags: git

I did git pull and got a message saying use git prune to remove unwanted files. Now I want to get back those deleted files . I cannot do git reset as these files were only on my local. Is there a way to retrieve those files?

Comment: `git prune` does not touch your work-tree, it only removes Git's internal object files in `.git/objects/ab/cdef0123...` (and then only ones that are *unreachable*, in Git's terminology, which means Git is no longer using them for anything).

Comment: but i hadn't executed any other commands. Do you know any way to restore deleted local files?

Comment: If the files were stored as Git commits, it's easy. If they were not ... well, then it's up to your OS to provide a way to get the files back. In any case a [mcve] might help diagnose what, precisely, went wrong. (This link is about source code, rather than commands, but the same *idea* applies.)